# Conditional formatting if cell value (name of day) equals today

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting, google-sheets-formula

For some reason this formula works in a cell but not as conditional formatting (A24 cell value = `Tuesday`):

[image]

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct formula is:

```
=if(A10=text(today(),"dddd"),true,false)
```

Producing this output ( run on a tuesday!) for sample data shown, these ranges:`A10:A17,C10:C17,E10:E17`

[image]

Obviously plug in your own ranges!

Comment: Yes, exactly what I looked for. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The [Accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53060843/1505120) won't work for the range shown by OP (and is longer than necessary - it is *Conditional* Formatting). The OP's attempt will work however with a small modification to remove the IF (replace by `=`) and adjustment by one row:

```
 =A23=text(today(),"dddd")
```

Example created on a Sunday:

[image: SO53056831 example]